# I have joined few tables and need total of the last column on the end of my query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have wrote SQL query pulling 6 columns from 4 different tables, however I need on the last row total just for one column. It should look like this.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can do:

```
with cte as (
      <your query here>
     )
select cte.*
from cte
union all
select 'Total', 'n/a', 'n/a', 'n/a', 'n/a', 'n/a', sum(consentv), 'n/a'
from cte;
```

Notes:

- This does not guarantee that `Total'` is at the end.  You might need `order by`.
- This assumes that all other columns have strings.

Comment: thank you so much, it works great, exactly what I need